# Extract part of string matching pattern

Tags: php, regex, string, multidimensional-array

I would like to scan a large piece of text using PHP and find all matches for a pattern, but then also 2 lines above the match and 2 lines below.

My text looks like this, but with some extra unnecessary text above and below this sample:

> 1
>
> Description text
>
> **123.456.12**
>
> 10.00
>
> 10.00
>
> 3
>
> Different Description text
>
> **234.567.89**
>
> 10.00
>
> 30.00
>
> *#Some footer text that is not needed and will change for each text file#*
>
> 15
>
> More description text
>
> **564.238.02**
>
> 4.00
>
> 60.00
>
> 15
>
> More description text
>
> **564.238.02**
>
> 4.00
>
> 60.00
>
> *#Some footer text that is not needed and will change for each text file#*
>
> 15
>
> More description text
>
> **564.238.02**
>
> 4.00
>
> 60.00
>
> 15
>
> More description text
>
> **564.238.02**
>
> 4.00
>
> 60.00

Using PHP, I am looking to match each number in bold *(always same format - 3 numbers, dot, 3 numbers, dot, 2 numbers)* but then also return the previous 2 lines and the next 2 lines and hopefully return an array so that I can use:

```
$contents[$i]["qty"] = "1";
$contents[$i]["description"] = "Description text";
$contents[$i]["price"] = "10.00";
$contents[$i]["total"] = "10.00";
```

etc...

Is this possible and would I use regex?  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

**ANSWERED BY vzwick**

This is my final code that I used:

```
$items_array = array();
$counter = 0;

if (preg_match_all('/(\d+)\n\n(\w.*)\n\n(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})\n\n(\d.*)\n\n(\d.*)/', $text_file, $matches)) {

    $items_string = $matches[0];
    foreach ($items_string as $value){

        $item = explode("\n\n", $value);

        $items_array[$counter]["qty"] = $item[0];
        $items_array[$counter]["description"] = $item[1];
        $items_array[$counter]["number"] = $item[2];
        $items_array[$counter]["price"] = $item[3];
        $items_array[$counter]["total"] = $item[4];

        $counter++;

    }

}
else
{
    die("No matching patterns found");
}

print_r($items_array);
```

Comment: Is it always chunks of 5 lines?

Comment: There will be other text above and below the sample I posted, but within the loop of items, it will always be chunks of 5 lines.

Comment: Also, the bold number will always be in the same format - 3 numbers, dot, 3 numbers, dot, 2 numbers

Comment: I've also just realised that although within the loop of items it will always be chunks of 5 lines, the text file could span multiple pages and therefore have a footer that I would need to ignore.  That was why I wondered if you can match the bold number and then collect that, the previous two lines and the next two lines as other text would then be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filename = "yourfile.txt";
$fp = @fopen($filename, "r");
if (!$fp) die('Could not open file ' . $filename);

$i = 0; // element counter
$n = 0; // inner element counter

$field_names = array('qty', 'description', 'some_number', 'price', 'total');
$result_arr = array();

while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
    $result_arr[$i][$field_names[$n]] = trim($line);
    $n++;
    if ($n % count($field_names) == 0) {
        $i++;
        $n = 0;
    }
}

fclose($fp);
print_r($result_arr);
```

**Edit:** Well, regex then.

```
$filename = "yourfile.txt";
$file_contents = @file_get_contents($filename);
if (!$file_contents) die("Could not open file " . $filename . " or empty file");
if (preg_match_all('/(\d+)\n\n(\w.*)\n\n(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})\n\n(\d.*)\n\n(\d.*)/', $file_contents, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
    // do your matching to field names from here ..
}
else
{
    die("No matching patterns found");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, edited my post to say that there will be other text in the text file too, above and below the sample I posted.  I don't need this and so would need to ignore it.

Comment: But your data is all in one chunk, right? Is there any delimiter?

Comment: No, sorry I meant to post that originally.  I'll update my sample text to show you what can happen...

Comment: Thanks, but just tried your code and it is returning "No matching patterns found" for the sample I posted.

Comment: \*sigh\* Are your lines delimited by double newlines? If so, check the update.

Comment: That was it! Awesome, it's working!  Thank you very much and sorry I made you sigh...

Answer (score 1):

```
(.)+\n+(.)+\n+(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})\n+(.)+\n+(.)+
```

It might be necessary to replace \n with \r\n. Make sure the regex is in a mode when the "." doesn't match with the new line character.

To reference groups by names, use named capturing group:

```
(?P<name>regex)
```

[example](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php#89418) of named capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the file in an array, and them use array_slice, to slice each 5 blocks of lines.

```
<?php

$file = file("myfile");
$finalArray = array();

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($file); $i = $i+5)
{
    $finalArray[] = array_slice($file, $i, 5); 
}

print_r($finalArray);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but see my updated sample and comments that there will be other text in the file that I don't need, hence the reason why I am only looking to match the bold number pattern and then get the previous 2 lines and the next 2 lines